# What is a basis and dimension of $\operatorname{span}\{I,M,M^2,...\}$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $M$ is invertible square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Putting all vectors (matrices) in one gives

$$        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & m_1 & \cdots\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & m_2 & \cdots\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & m_3 & \cdots\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

The reduced row echelon form of this matrix is always that matrix.

Does this mean that the dimension of $\operatorname{span}\{I,M,M^2,...\}$ is $3$ and a basis is formed of column vectors of identity matrix?

But because $I$ can't be represented as a linear combination of, for example, $M$ and $M^2$, from here it follows that a basis for $\operatorname{span}\{I,M,M^2,...\}$ is an empty set and the dimension is $0$.

Which is correct?

Comment: 1: The matrix you give is not square. 2: A basis of your $\text{span}$ will consist of matrices, not of (column) vectors. 3: I can't make sense of your last sentence about representing $I$. Would you care to expand?

Comment: What is the matrix $M$?

Comment: @Bernard  $M$ is invertible squared matrix over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I understood that.  I mean ‘What is $M$ w.r.t. the displayed matrix in the second line of your post?’

Comment: @Bernard A matrix that contains of all matrices from $span$ set. Finding $rref$ of that matrix would result in knowing the set of linearly independent vector that form a basis. Note that I arbitrarily chose $n=3$ is the order of matrices in $span$ set.

Comment: @user400044 *"finding the rref of that matrix would result in knowing the set of linearly independent vector that form a basis":* that tricks only works with column-vectors.  This would **not** work.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Could you explain how to find a basis for $span$ set?

Comment: @user300044 you would have to [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) the matrices, and *then* put them into a matrix as you have.

Answer (score 1):

Dimension has to be the degree of the minimal polynomial of M

Comment: Perhaps it would improve the answer to explain why.

Comment: Because the minimal polynomial gives u relation between the powers of M and that can be used to eliminate the dependent powers..ex if the minimal polynomial is of degree m say then u get M^m=linear combination of I,M.......M^m-1.hence the dimension m..i hope it helps

Comment: My point is that, for someone who knows about the minimal polynomial but doesn't see the connection with the question, this answer is not likely to be very illuminating without some more details.

Comment: Could you enlighten mein with that "for someone"of yours

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: @user311790 it is very likely, for example, that the asker of the question has never heard of "minimal polynomials" at all, so this answer would not be particularly illuminating.

Comment: @user311790 also, you should have included something addressing the second part of the question, i.e. "the matrices $\{I,M,\dots,M^d\}$ (where $d$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial) form a basis of this span".

Answer (score 1):

Every square matrix is a zero of its own minimal polynomial. So plugging $M$ into its minimal polynomial gives a linear combination of powers of $M$ which is equal to zero, making these powers of $M$ linearly dependent. This shows that the dimension of your space is at most the degree of the minimal polynomial. By minimality of the degree of the minimal polynomial, the dimension of your space is *exactly* the degree of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: How to find a basis for $span\{I,M,...\}$? If $\dim(span)=n$, then how to find $n$ matrices from $span$ to form a basis?

Comment: @user300044 It turns out, in your particular case, that the matrices $\{I,M,\dots,M^n\}$ can always be taken as your basis (if the dimension of the span is $n$).

Comment: @Omnomnom I think you mean $\{I,M,\ldots,M^{n-1}\}$ is a basis if the dimension of the span is $n$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean